# Print Colored Font Into Excel Using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to print a green, bold font into an excel spreadsheet.

I can print this in jupyter notebook without a problem, but this is what I get in the spreadsheet: [1m[92mHello

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('out.xlsx')
pd.DataFrame([1,'\033[1m' + '\033[92m'+ 'Hello',3]).to_excel(writer, sheet_name= 'sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Comment: Any reason why you are using pandas for this? Why don't you use `xlwings` ([Docs](https://www.xlwings.org/))

Comment: I retrieve the data from a database then write to excel. That's the final output. I'm a newbie with pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas` cannot achieve that.
You can use `openpyxl` to do so.
So what you have to do is export your data into excel using `pandas`, and then load the workbook using `openpyxl` and handle the coloring and other visualisation aspects from there.

```
from openpyxl.styles import colors
from openpyxl.styles import Font, Color
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = load_workbook('yourworkbookname.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
a1 = ws['A1']
d4 = ws['D4']
ft = Font(color=colors.GREEN, bold=True)
a1.font = ft
d4.font = ft
wb.save()
```

For more documentation into `openpyxl`, visit [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html)

Comment: is there a function to close the workbook once I'm done writing to it?

Comment: @DonCheeto Yeah included `wb.save()`. I'm slightly rusty but there could be a `wb.close()` too. You can test that out haha

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `ExcelWriter` classes and methods to do many things in the workbook/worksheet. To do what you are intending to do, do the following.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('out.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
pd.DataFrame([1,'Hello',3]).to_excel(writer, sheet_name= 'sheet1')
worksheet = writer.sheets['sheet1']
workbook = writer.book
cell_format = workbook.add_format({'bold':True, 'font_color': 'green'})
worksheet.set_row(2,None,cell_format)
writer.save()
```

Documentation of [ExcelWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/index.html)

Also, If you are trying to change the format of the header, you have to reset the header style first. Put the following before defining the `writer`

```
pd.io.formats.excel.header_style = None
```